# PageviewController is not showing the viewcontrollers in correct order

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to work with a `PageviewController`. I have 4 `ViewControllers` but they are all different. In one I have an image, in the second I have a tableview,...

I want to scroll through it with a `pageviewController`. So what I did is the following. I've added them to a `modelArray`.

```
ViewOneViewController *viewOne = (ViewOneViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewOne"];
ViewTwoViewController *viewTwo = (ViewTwoViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewTwo"];
ViewThreeViewController *viewThree = (ViewThreeViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewThree"];
ViewFourViewController *viewFour =(ViewFourViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewFour"];

self.modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:viewOne,viewTwo,viewThree,viewFour,nil];
```

Next I set up my pageviewController like this.

```
 ViewOneViewController *cVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewOne"];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cVC];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Now to browse through the pageviewViewController I have the following functions.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    indexValue--;
    if (indexValue < 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:indexValue];
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    indexValue++;
    if (indexValue > self.modelArray.count) {
        NSLog(@"crash");
        return nil;
    }
    return [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:indexValue];
}
```

I have declared and synthesized `indexValue` as an `int`. But for some reason or another it is showing me sometimes two times the ViewOneController or it goes from ViewOneController to ViewThreeController and so on.

Can someone help me?

Kind regards

**EDIT**

When I do this.

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:self.modelArray direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

It crashes with this error

**'The number of view controllers provided (4) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition'**

Comment: I see that you set your page's view controllers to contain only the first view controller. Is that on purpose ?

Comment: If I fill the array viewControllers with more then one viewController the app crashes

Comment: I never used the page controller but from the docs it seems that you need to set all your view controllers so maybe there is a problem with how you set them ?

Comment: I've edited my post with what you are suggesting and the error

Comment: How are you getting the index of the current view controller on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code.

1. The method `setViewControllers:` sets the current controllers visible. Settings the `self.modelArray` is incorrect, because it contains all the pages you have. You need to use it once the UIPageViewController initializes (and if you want to force change current page).
2. You use `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` not right way. There's no need in `indexValue` class member. In this methods you should find out which controller is the next (from `viewController` method parameter) or previous and return another controller.

Look at this code:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewOneViewController class]]) {
        return nil;
    } else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ViewTwoViewController class]]) {
        return [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:0]; // return ViewOneViewController class instance
    } else if 
    //... etc
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // vice versa
}
```

3. When you store all the controller in one array it might use a lot of memory. I advice you not to keep in `modelArray` property, but instantiate it in `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocol methods.

Good luck.